# How can I increase bifido bacterium strain density in kefir

Tags: fermentation, kefir

Both water and milk kefir contain Bifido strains and I would like a way to increase the density of bifido strains.

If the variety of strains could also be increased, that would be a bonus.

Bifido is anaerobic and consumes oligosaccharides (I think), so could adding juiced chickpeas after initial fermentation has removed all the oxygen work?

Comment: You should add some more details regarding your fermentation process. Also, Bifidobacterium has many strains. Perhaps you can add those details too. I don't think we have many experts on home fermentation. I think you may get more useful answers at [cooking.se] and I shall migrate the question there. But please add all necessary details.

Comment: Dear Simon:  Why would you like to increase the density of bifido strains?

Comment: My fermentation process is this;
1.5 ltrs filtered water + 6 tablespoons of raw sugar and a tiny pinch of sea salt.
24 hours of primary fermentation then add 0.5 litrs of fruit juice (apply/mango).
24 hours of secondary fermentation then chill and consume.

Comment: @unforgettableid.
I am treating a gut issue, and I have found I have a genetic defect that means I do not secrete a certain gut protein which is used to feed bifido bacteria. 

People with this defect have been shown to have half the levels of bifido as well as half the verieties of bifido strains, compared to normal controls.

Kefir has always helped me, but I need it every day, and it's still not quite enough - I'm thinking this may be the root cause. 
The gene in question is FUT2 - Fucosyltransferase 2.

Consuming galactooligofructose may help, as well as more bifido strains.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to increase the diversity of strains might be to start from a mixture of kefirs from the most diverse and independent sources you can find. There's no guarantee that putting two symbiotic communities together will improve either of them though, or produce a final more diverse community.

What are the constraints on density? I would imagine that density will increase until either nutrients are depleted, or pH or other toxicity factors reach a certain limit. You might find that some strains tolerate a higher/lower pH range than others, and also that careful pH adjustment would allow density to keep increasing, provided you supply enough nutrient.

Comment: Thanks.
So alternative mil and water kefir may work better than combining?

PH toxicity would seem to not be too much of a worry, as stomach acid will be much lower PH than kefir, so only acid resistant microbes would bet to the gut anyway I would think?

Since I only ferment for 48 hours, I'd think the growth would slow as the more easily fermentable sugars get consumed (by lactic acid species?).

I think I'll try secondary fermentation with bifido specific food sources.

Unfortunately, I have no way to gauge success.